# Building Android library with Eclipse vs Ant

Tags: android, ant, continuous-integration, android-library, eclipse-adt

I have a simple Android library project, which contains network calls functionality only. It doesn't need to inherit any XML/resources etc… to calling application. When I build this project using Eclipse IDE (right click on project and click on <kbd>Build Project</kbd>), it generates a JAR under `bin/libproject.jar`. I can simply drop this file to any project's build path and it works fine.

Now, I want to implement continuous integration for my library. That means, I need some command-line way to achieve the same (building jar, when I build the project using `ant`). Ant builds the project differently. It creates `classes.jar` in `bin/` folder, which is not the same as as `libproject.jar`.

I believe Eclipse's <kbd>Build Project</kbd> (ADT rev-21) is doing something magical to build this complete JAR for my library project (this is more like a java project like JAR).

Do you know how can I achieve the same using command line?

Comment: Q: could you post the relevant portions of your build.xml?

Comment: you might wanna check this: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject or http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Comment: @paulsm4: this is the default build.xml that gets generated after updating a project from commandline: android update project -p

Comment: @zoyaali: I'm already doing that. I'm able to build the project using commandline, but it doesn't generate the stand alone JAR as Eclipse does.

Answer (score 0):

im using eclipse 4.3 w/ ant and with sdk tools 21.1

IMO - they recently changed the sdk regarding lib dependencies.

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

see the above link.

my example lib dependency(transitive) as follows:

ABS <== SlidingMenu <== MyProject

so, in SM.project.properties...
   android.library.reference.1=../../src/ABS/library

and, in MP.project.properties ...
   android.library.reference.1=../../src/SlidingMenu/library

The ant build, run on proj=SM using either eclipse internal, ant build tools OR ant on CLI in a terminal session outside eclipse 
does following:

```
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 [echo] Creating library output jar file...
  [jar] Building jar: /home/rob/src/tools/ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0/library/bin/classes.jar
```

and ant build, run on proj=MP does the following:

```
      Setting project property: out.library.jar.file -> /home/rob/src/SlidingMenu/library/bin/classes.jar
..
      [jar] Building jar: /home/rob/src/SlidingMenu/library/bin/classes.jar
```

IMO - you should focus on 2 things :

get the lib reference correct in the file=project.properties of the dependent.

double check in eclipse the  project /properties/ java build path / order and export

read the link as it contains multiple , specific NOTEs relating to 'order export'...

When you build the dependent project in ant , it should trigger internally, builds of the other projects. I think that is controlled in the build path of the dependent project.

An additional NOTE on debugging - i could not debug directly from the project explorer because the launcher did not like the "classes.jar" for the 2 , dependent projects. Debug insisted on there being jars with names "${project-name}.jar" in the ./bin directory of each library. But ant assigns "classes.jar" as shown above.

So, to debug, i used the alternate method of DDMS tab in eclipse w/ the app already running. then u find the process and attach the debugger.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I didn't understand whats the difference b/w "classes.jar" and "${project-name}.jar". When I run ant, I get "classes.jar" in bin/ folder, but when I build from eclipse, I get "${project-name}.jar" in bin/ folder. Are these two same ?

Comment: unpack the 2 jar files to see if they are the same .. my guess is that the contents will be the same.

Comment: btw-you can use 'ant.properties' to assign a diff name to the jar file .   it will no longer be classes.jar and could be projectname.jar even from ant buid

Comment: @RobertRowntree: That breaks builds if you're building another project that depends on the library, since it'll still try to pull in "classes.jar".